# Stop visual studio 2019 from higlighting occurences of word under the cursor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, highlight

Visual studio 2019 keeps on highlighting occurences of the word under my cursor in the current file:
[image]

Is there a way I can get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> References -> "Disable Reference Highlighting"

Set to true.